# Need to check answer for this probability question!

Tags: probability

[image]

For this question I wanted to check my answer, I got the answer to be $\frac{1}{36}$. Could someone check this for me please.

I used Bayes' rule with

event A= three numbers are equal

event B= all odd/no even

Got P(A)$=\frac{6}{6^3}$

P(B given A)$=\frac{1}{2}$

P(B given not A)$=\frac{1}{2}$

Then substituted in to formula for P(A given B).

Comment: How did you get $18/35$? This would mean that if you roll three dice and the three are not all equal, there is greater than a 50% chance all three numbers are odd. That’s not possible, since the numbers being not all equal can’t make odd results more likely than even (or mixed).

Comment: @ Steve Kass I got 1/36 as my answer now

Comment: Your value of $\dfrac{1}{2}$ for P(B given not A) is still wrong. Given not A (given that the three numbers are not all the same), the probability all the numbers are odd is the same as the probability all the numbers are even, but each of these is less than $\dfrac{1}{2}$, because it can also be the case that both odd and even numbers show up. If three things can happen and two of them are equally likely, those two cannot each have probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$. How are you figuring out P(B given not A)?

Comment: @ Steve Kass I did ((6^3)/2)-3)/(6^3)-6, so to work out the sample points such that all 3 numbers are different I did (6^3)-6 in the denominator

Comment: @ Steve Kass and for numerator I did 216/2=108 which are all sample points such that all three values are odd minus 3 for the values which are the same e.g, 111,333,555.

Comment: Your numerator is wrong. $216/2$ is half the possible rolls. This is not how many of the rolls have all three values odd. (Again, you can apply common sense. You could have all values odd, you could have all values even, and you could have some even and some odd. All values odd can’t account for half the possibilities.) Similarly, if you needed to know how many ways you could flip 1000 coins and get all heads, you wouldn’t say $\dfrac{2^{1000}}{2}$, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Using your definitions of $A$ and $B$, we want $\Pr(A|B)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$. We have $\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{8}$.

For $\Pr(A\cap B)$, the numbers can be equal and odd in $3$ ways, so $\Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{3}{6^3}$.

Note that $\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{8}$. 
Divide.

**Remark:** It turns out that $\Pr(A|B)=\frac{1}{9}$. A little thinking will show that this answer is obvious, and the conditional probability machinery we used is not really needed. For in effect we have tossed a three-sided die, and we want the probability the results are all the same. Whatever the result of te first toss was, the probability of matching it twice is $\frac{1}{3^2}$.